# C# унаследовать класс сразу от нескольких классов, не изменяю родительские классы

Tags: c#, множественное-наследование

у меня есть класс, к примеру: MyClass. И при работе в нём, я хочу пользоваться методами других классов(системных), но я не хочу в каждом методе заново определять объекты этих классов, я просто хочу обращаться к элементам системных классов, с помощью: `this.SystemClass`. Всё прекрасно, когда я наследую только один родительский класс. Но я хочу добавить их больше, естественно c# не поддерживает множественное наследование. Я пришёл к использованию интерфейсов, конкретно к этой схеме:

```cs
class SystemClass1
{
  m1();
}

interface ISystemClass2
{
  m2();
}

class SystemClass2 : ISystemClass2
{
  m2();
}

class C : SystemClass1, ISystemClass2
{
  SystemClass2 BObject;
  m1();
  m2() { BObject.m2(); }
}
```

Но здесь нам надо прописать наследование в родительском(в моём случае системном классе). Вопрос, как мне унаследоваться от двух системных классов?

P.S в C# нуб(знаю его 2 дня, вернее не знаю его :D ) поэтому пожалуйста понятнее

Comment: Всё верно, множественного наследования в C# нет. Поэтому придётся использовать композицию/агрегацию и создавать объекты других классов, чтобы обращаться к их методам.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov эхх... Ну хорошо, тогда не подскажите как создавать объекты других классов в конструкторе, чтобы они были доступны в каждом методе моего класса?

Comment: Один класс - одна ответственность. А у вас какой-то класс-зомби-мутант. Пример который вы привели к реальной ситуации не относится, необходимости в таком не существует.

Comment: Добро пожаловать в мир внедрения зависимостей (DI), глядите, скоро и до IoC дойдете, а там и до контейнеров, которые за вас будут внедрять все.

Comment: Гляньте пожалуйста если не сложно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1348865/423786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наследование в первую очередь нужно для реализации общих публичных членов классов, когда между классами есть общее - родитель. Это позволяет избежать дублирования кода.

Наследование полезно тогда, когда хочется создать коллекцию из разных классов, при этом пользоваться их общими методами от родителя не приводя к конкретному типу. Здесь на помщь приходит еще полиморфизм.

Наследование идет от абстрактного к конкретному.

Когда вы наследуете конкретный тип от абстракции, он перенимает все реализации родителя на себя. Если вам вдруг для какой-то задачи потребовалось 2 родителя, например:

```cs
class A1 { }
class A2 { }

class B : A1, A2 { } // ошибка компиляции
```

Тогда вы столкнетесь с ограничением языка C#, потому что наследоваться можно только от одного родителя.

Если вам нужны члены обоих базовых классов в наследнике, при необходимости, это ограничение можно обойти унаследовав базовые классы один от второго:

```cs
class A1 { }
class A2 : A1 { }

class B : A2 { }
```

Но этот обход не всегда подходит, в зависимости от конкретной задачи. Или как в вашем случае, когда технически невозможно изменить реализацию родителей так, чтобы они наследовались друг от друга.

Наследование используется для сборки целостного объекта, который полноценно умеет что-то делать. Но при такой сборке класса обычно учитывается Принцип единой ответственности (SRP из SOLID), это когда класс умеет что-то делать одно и в рамках единой задачи.

То есть если это к примеру класс "Бомба", то он умеет только тикать и взрываться, он не умеет себя запускать или останавливать, переносить из одного угла комнаты в другой, мяукать или стирать шнурки. Только тикать и взрываться.

То есть, другими словами, просто желание инкапсулировать в один класс всё подряд - не повод для наследования от всего что нужно. Наследование - не для этого используется. Если вам нужна мяукающая перед взрывом бомба, создайте класс "Мяукало", передайте его в конструктор "Бомбы" и пусть она использует это мяукало перед взрывом. Такой подход облегчит доработку приложения например, вы однажды передумали и решили что она будет мяукать не в консоль, а в наушники. И ура, если вы всё верно предусмотрели, то изменения в класс "Бомбы" вообще не придется вносить. Это и есть та самая польза от принципа единой отвественности.

---

Кстати, передача экземпляра класса в конструктор другого класса - по-модному называется "внедрение зависимости" (DI = Dependency Injection), а если быть конкретнее, то "внедрение в конструктор" (Constructor Injection). И если вы однажды...точнее не если, а...когда вы однажды заинтересуртесь, как же из этой кучи классов собрать единое целое и ни где не накосячить, при этом максимально быстро и просто в эту кучу добавлять новые компоненты, вы рано или поздно наткнетесь на класс, который умеет втыкать зависимости в конструкторы (и не только в них) автоматически. Когда какой-то класс сам решает, где взять экземпляр, требуемый для текущего класса в конструкторе и создает этот экземпляр для вас автоматически - называется что он взял управление экземлярами на себя. То есть не текущий класс создает экземпляры с помощью `new`, а какой-то другой, это называется "инверсия управления" (IoC = Inversion of Control), и такой управляющий класс называется "контейнер", об этом выше в комментарии и написал @EvgeniyZ. Не торопитесь в эту тему нырять, она не для начинающих, просто пока вам достаточно знать, что оно вот такое есть.

Ах, да, есть еще же интерфейсы. Так вот, они к наследованию имеют очень косвенное отношение. Их задача определить шаблон публичной реализации для текущего класса, вы не сможете определить в интерфейсе приватные члены. Реализовать один и тот же интерфейс могут совершенно не связанные родственными связями между собой классы. Один класс может реализовывать (не наследовать, а именно реализовывать) несколько интерфейсов одновременно.

Comment: Спасибо, но всё же я думаю мне придётся нырнуть туда именно сейчас, потому что других вариантов реализации  я не вижу

Answer (score 2):

Если нужны только статические методы классов, то можно их подключить локально:

```
using static System.Math;
using static System.Threading.Thread;
```

И потом в коде их можно будет использовать сокращённо:

```
int max = Max(1,2);
//вместо System.Math.Max(1,2);

int id = CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
//вместо System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

Можно пойти чуть дальше и натянуть сову на глобус с костылями:

```
class MyStaticMethods
{
    public static string GiveMeHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

using static MyStaticMethods;
string hello = GiveMeHello(); //вместо MyStaticMethods.GiveMeHello();
```

Можно пойти чуть дальше и смешать всё это с кислотой, сделав динамическую реализацию:

```
interface IMyConfigure
{ 
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object UniversalContainer { get; set; }
}
class MyConfigure
{
    public static IMyConfigure MyConfig { get; set; }
    public static bool IsMyConfigExist => MyConfig != null;
    public static int GiveMePort()
    {
        return MyConfig.Port;
    }
    public static string GiveMeName()
    {
        return MyConfig.Name;
    }
    public static object GiveMeUniversalContainer()
    {
        return MyConfig.UniversalContainer;
    }
}
class ShelockMyConfigure : IMyConfigure
{
    public int Port { get; set; } = 1;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Bubenchik";
    public object UniversalContainer { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

И получить уже не совсем статическое поведение:

```
using static MyConfigure;

MyConfig = new ShelockMyConfigure() { Port = 2 };
GiveMePort() //2
GiveMeName() //"Bubenchik"
GiveMeUniversalContainer() //момент первого обращения
```

Не полноценно то, что нужно, но где-то да поможет, всё локально загнать не получится.

Comment: @artemgh тогда в ``MyConfigure`` вам нужно добавить соответствующие методы, которые будут перенаправлять свои вызовы на ``IMyConfigure`` где и будет храниться текущее подключение.

Comment: можно немного подробнее?

Comment: @artemgh самый простой вариант: просто в свой класс добавляете одноимённые методы, которые используются в классах работы с тем, что вам нужно. И всё, пусть они перенаправляют вызовы до объекта, который изначально выполняет эту работу.

Comment: Как мне кажется, проще привыкнуть к реалиям дотнета и доставать методы и классы оттуда, где они лежат не притягивая их статическими юзингами, а только подключать неймспейсы. Типа `using System;` и `Math.Max()`. Статические юзинги конечно немного укорачивают код, но они же затрудняют его чтение другими разработчиками, кому-то это удобно, кому-то нет. И в командной разработке лучше пользоваться общепринятыми методами написания кода. Плюсану ответ, потому что он показывает полезный набор инструментов, несмотря на то что я считаю, что этот набор нужно использовать не повсеместно, а с умом.