# Как объявить объект другого класса в конструкторе и иметь возможность работать с ним в деструкторе?

Tags: c#

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
class Myclass{
  public Myclass():SqliteCommand
  {
    SqliteConneciton connection = new SqliteConnection();
    this.Connection = conneciton; // Это к слову, зачем мне вообще это всё
    connection.Open();
  }
  /* Какие то другие методы */
  ~Myclass()
  {
    connection.Close();// Но это естественно не работает(
  }
}
```

Здесь я в конструкторе создаю экземпляр класса `SqliteConneciton();`. Вопрос, как мне работать с этим экземпляром в деструкторе (пытался записать его в переменную `var connection = new SqliteConnection()`. Но это переменная локальная и этот подход тоже не работает

Comment: `IDisposable` - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable

Comment: Локальные переменные на то и локальные, что их нельзя где-то еще использовать кроме как внутри блока кода. Создайте поле ```SqliteConnection``` и реализуйте интерфейс ```IDisposable```, в вашем методе Dispose() вызовите ```SqliteConnection.Dispose()```

Comment: `~` - это не деструктор, а финализатор. [Finalizers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers). Вызывается он в неопределённое время по воле сборщика мусора, поэтому не получится использовать его так, как вы планировали. Как уже посоветовали, используйте освобождение ресурсов с помощью реализации `IDisposable`.

Comment: Отмечу, что уже вкрай задолбали классы, наподобие приведённого в вопросе: бессмысленные обёртки над SqlConnection, применение которых нисколько не сокращает и не упрощает код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а как вы предлагаете реализовать работу с бд? Я не против каких-либо изменений и не настаиваю что это лучшая реализация

Comment: Создавать соединение прямо в месте использования: `using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();
        // используем соединение
    }` И не нужны классы-обёртки.

Comment: Но я не спорю, смысл может быть. Просто пока я его не вижу, т. к. пример слишком обрезанный.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это всё хорошо, но мне также нужно записывать, удалять, читать и изменять данные, что я делаю в этом классе, сейчас ещё без особой готовности уже занимает 100+ строк

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, здесь слишком упрошенный пример

Comment: `this.Connection` - это что? Поле или свойство. Вот его и надо использовать в другом методе: `Connection.Close();`. Только **не** в финализаторе!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а будет сильным костылём если я оберну большое количество функций в using?

Comment: Сколько угодно можно вставлять внутрь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov this.Connection, здесь я пытаюсь в свойство положить метод другого класса (SqliteConnection)

Comment: Кстати когда я пытаюсь закрыть `this.Connection.Close()` Visual studio не выдает ошибку, но подчеркивает зеленой волнистой линией

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov всё конечно, отлично работает, но мне кажется использовать в каждом методе класса `using conn = new SqliteConnection()` немного костылем, получается я очень часто открываю и закрываю его, просто так, зная что оно мне ещё понадобится

Comment: Если используется пулинг (pooling), то ничего страшного в этом нет. Соединение будет в пуле оставаться открытым.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot Вы были правы, конечно спасибо, за ответ, но я всё же, решил не делать этот класс, а сделать классы для каждого вида объектов, и уже там в каждом методе отдельно создавать экземпляры класса)

Comment: @artemgh то есть, вы игнорируете реализацию IDisposable, [нехорошо](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

Comment: @aepot я просто подумал, что глупо делать, так, как я делал, хотя я и не до конца понял IDisposable, гляну вашу статью)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь надо понять просто правила работы с `IDisposable` объектами.

- [Реализация метода Dispose](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

```cs
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed;
    private readonly SqliteConnection connection;

    public MyClass()
    {
        connection = new SqliteConnection();
        connection.Open();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SupressFinalize(this); // предотвращает последующий вызов финализатора
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    { 
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(MyClass));

            // здесь выполняется очистка управляемых ресурсов
            // другими словами, не нужно диспозить объекты при вызове из финализатора
            connection.Dispose();
        }

        // здесь обычно выполняется очистка неуправляемых ресурсов
        // но у вас их нет

        disposed = true;
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

В данном конкретном случае поле `connection` не рекомендуется делать публичным.

Далее все как с любым другим `IDisposable` классом:

```cs
using var instance = new MyClass();
// ...
```

или для старых версий C# вот так:

```cs
using (var instance = new MyClass())
{
    // ...
}
```